# How can the RetryOptions of an AWS Kinesis Firehose's RedshiftDestinationConfiguration be managed via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose

- The AWS CLI API defines a *RedshiftDestinationConfiguration* of a *Kinesis Firehose* as having a *RetryOptions* parameter.
  [ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_RedshiftDestinationConfiguration.html)
- The cloudformation schema also defines a *RedshiftDestinationConfiguration* of a *Kinesis Firehose* but has no *RetryOptions* parameter.
  [ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-kinesisdeliverystream-redshiftdestinationconfiguration.html)

Is there a way to set and update the retry options of a firehose that is being maintained via cloudformation files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`AWS::KinesisFireHose::DeliveryStream`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html) Resource was initially added to CloudFormation on [June 9 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/06/aws-cloudformation-adds-support-for-amazon-vpc-flow-logs-amazon-kinesis-firehose-streams-and-other-updates/), while the Amazon Redshift COPY retry feature was added on [May 18, 2016](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/history.html). (Presumably the CloudFormation resource was originally implemented before the `RetryOptions` parameter was finalized.)

Unfortunately, unlike other AWS SDKs which tend to track new AWS features more closely, there's generally a significant lag between new AWS feature announcements and their implementation in CloudFormation resources.

Until AWS implements this feature in the official AWS CloudFormation resource, you can implement a workaround using a [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that calls [`UpdateDestination`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateDestination.html) directly to set the unsupported `RetryOptions` parameter.